# Differentiable but not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $f(x)=x^2\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ whenever $x\neq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $0$ but not continuous at $0$, and this is a contradiction?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: No it is just false.  It is continuous at $0$.

Comment: It is both continuous and differentiable at $0$.

Comment: $sin \frac{1}{x}$ oscillates wildly between $-1$ and $1$, and $x^2$ goes to zero as $x \rightarrow 0$, so their product goes to zero. Defining $f(x) = 0$ makes $f$ continuous at $0$.

Comment: Here's another cool function. Continuous everywhere, but differentiable nowhere. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition given in Rudin (p.85) “$f$ has to be defined at the point $p$ in order to be continuous at $p$.”  So $x^{2} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is not continuous, as this function is certainly not defined at $0$, though its limit is, and the $\lim_{x \to0} x^{2} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 0$.

As you have defined your $f(0)$ to equal the limit the function approaches as it goes to zero (and since this was the only problem with continuity and differentiability in the earlier case), your function is continuous, and also differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

All differentiable function are continuous but not all continuous function are differentiable

**Example:**
$F(x)=x \sin(1/x)$ is continuous but not differentiable

Comment: I'd turn that “all are not” into “not all are”. I.e. write $\neg\forall$ instead of $\forall\neg$.

Comment: @MvG All people do not have the same proficiency in English =)